# Datatable plugin doesn't initialize

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

i have a simple table an i want to dynamise it with the datatable jquery pluging.

I don't understand why this is doesn't work :

http://jsfiddle.net/barnab21/hovcmaa8/

Maybe because of my links ?

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

here my js:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#tableau_user').dataTable();
    } );
```

Answer (score 2):

Take this [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/hovcmaa8/1/)

Your table is wrong, look at updated table

```
    <table id="tab_user" class="tableau_utilisateurs">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Pseudonyme</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Date_inscription</th>
            <th>Administrateur</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>aaaaa</td>
            <td>bbbbbb</td>
            <td>ccccccc</td>
            <td>ddddddd</td>
            <td>eeeeee</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: To be more precise, his table isn't necessarily wrong, but the DataTable plugin requires the `thead`, `tbody` (and `tfoot` if desired) tags in order to work.